# Converting X, Z coords to RGB using GLSL shaders

Tags: colors, three.js, glsl, rgb

I have a Three js scene that contains a 100x100 plane centred at the origin (ie. min coord: (-50,-50), max coord: (50,50)). I am trying to have the plane appear as a colour wheel by using the x and z coords in a custom glsl shader. Using [this guide](https://thebookofshaders.com/06/) (see HSB in polar coordinates, towards the bottom of the page) I have gotten my
[Shader Code with Three.js Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCYB2.png)
but it is not quite right.

I have played around tweaking all the variables that make sense to me, but as you can see in the screenshot the colours change twice as often as what they should. My math intuition says just divide the angle by 2 but when I tried that it was completely incorrect.

I know the solution is very simple but I have tried for a couple hours and I haven't got it.

How do I turn my shader that I currently have into one that makes exactly 1 full colour rotation in 2pi radians?

EDIT: here is the relevant shader code in plain text

```
varying vec3 vColor;
                const float PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
                uniform float delta;
                uniform float scale;
                uniform float size;

                vec3 hsb2rgb( in vec3 c ){
                    vec3 rgb = clamp(abs(mod(c.x*6.0+vec3(0.0,4.0,2.0),
                                             6.0)-3.0)-1.0,
                                     0.0,
                                     1.0 );
                    rgb = rgb*rgb*(3.0-2.0*rgb);
                    return c.z * mix( vec3(1.0), rgb, c.y);
                }

                void main()
                {
                    vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
                    float r = 0.875;
                    float g = 0.875;
                    float b = 0.875;
                    if (worldPosition.y > 0.06 || worldPosition.y < -0.06) {
                        vec2 toCenter = vec2(0.5) - vec2((worldPosition.z+50.0)/100.0, (worldPosition.x+50.0)/100.0);
                        float angle = atan(worldPosition.z/worldPosition.x);
                        float radius = length(toCenter) * 2.0;
                        vColor = hsb2rgb(vec3((angle/(PI))+0.5,radius,1.0));
                    } else {
                        vColor = vec3(r,g,b);
                    }
                    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
                    gl_PointSize = size * (scale/length(mvPosition.xyz));
                    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
                }
```

Comment: In the book of shaders, there is `color = hsb2rgb(vec3((angle/TWO_PI)+0.5,radius,1.0));`, it uses `TWO_PI` define, that is PI * 2, whereas in your code you use just `PI`: `vColor = hsb2rgb(vec3((angle/(PI))+0.5,radius,1.0));`.

Comment: I know, I noticed that. When I try 2PI  it is much worse though. there are no reddish hues everything is blue/green.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the guide I was following was incorrect. I wasn't thinking about my math properly but I now know what the problem was.

atan has a range from -PI/2 to PI/2 which only accounts for half of a circle. When `worldPosition.x` is negative atan will not return the correct angle since it is out of range of the function. The angle needs to be adjusted based on what quadrant it is in the plane.

Q1: do nothing
Q2: add PI to the angle
Q3: add PI to the angle
Q4: add 2PI to the angle

After this normalize the angle (divide by 2PI) then pass it to the hsb2rgb function.